# How to solve this question simply?

Tags: probability

### Question

Let $X,Y$ be independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively. Prove the following:

1)$\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}$ and $X-Y$ are independent random variables conditional on $X>Y$

2)For any positive number $c>0$, we have $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}|X>Y+c]=\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}|X>Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}]=1/(\lambda +\mu)$

### My solution

Let $f_X(x),f_Y(y),f_{X,Y}(x.y)$ be PDF, $Z\!:=X-Y$

1)$\displaystyle f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\lambda \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x}\mu \mathrm{e}^{-\mu y}\quad \mathbb{P}[X>Y]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu}$

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}[\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}\leq y|X>Y]=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y|X>Y]=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y,X>Y]}{\mathbb{P}[X>Y]}=\dfrac{\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x}{\mathbb{P}[X>Y]}=\dfrac{\frac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)} \right)}{\frac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu}}=1-\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)y}$

$\mathbb{P}[X-Y\leq z|X>Y]=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}[X-Y\leq z,X>Y]}{\mathbb{P}[X>Y]}=\dfrac{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{y+z}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x}{\mathbb{P}[X>Y]}=\dfrac{\frac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda z} \right)}{\frac{\mu}{\lambda +\mu}}=1-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda z}$

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}[Y\leq y,Z\leq z|X>Y]=1-\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)y}+\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)y-\lambda z}-\mathrm{e}^{\lambda z}$

By calculating the question was proven.

2)$A\!:=\{X>Y+c\}$

$F_{Y|A}(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y|A]=\dfrac{\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y+c}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y+c}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x}=1-\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)y}$

$\displaystyle f_{Y|A}(y)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}F_{Y|A}(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda +\mu)y}}{\lambda +\mu}$

$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{min}\{X,Y\}|X>Y+c]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f_{Y|A}(y)\mathrm{d}y=\dfrac{1}{\lambda +\mu}$. Similarly, we can calculate other equations.

#### I spent much time calculating, I want to know if there is any better solution.

Comment: Are your distribution Poisson or Exponnentielle?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I asked this question.X and Y are both exponential variables.